# How to emulate right click options with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I want Capybara to click on "Back" option which is available after right click on page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using this code

```
page.evaluate_script('window.history.back()')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Capybara session has a built-in method, [Session#go_back](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#go_back-instance_method), for going back in the history:

```
page.go_back
```

It is not exactly what you asked for, but it gives the same result. I assume you are not actually trying to test the browser's context menu.

Comment: Actually I want to open the context menu and then I want click on back option from that context menu, Is this possible using capybara?

Comment: It is possible, but is not as robust. Is it a custom context menu and that is why you want to interact with it?

Comment: I am writing cucumber test case for this feature, So I want capybara to do right click on page anywhere and then click on the "Back" option available on  right click context menu.